# Error from stringr::str_glue_data()

Tags: r, stringr

Trying to use elementary tricks from https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_glue.html, I load the library and try several commands.  (The first use of str_glue_data() is pasted from the link; the others are attempts to debug by being successively more pedantic in syntax.)

```
library(stringr)
mtcars %>% str_glue_data("{rownames(.)} has {hp} hp")
str_glue_data(mtcars, "has hp {hp}")
str_glue_data(.x = mtcars, "has hp {hp}")
```

All three attempts to use the function result in

```
 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '.na' not found
```

My environment looks like:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringr_1.3.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5  tools_3.3.3   yaml_2.1.14   stringi_1.1.7
```

Wassup?  Thx.

Comment: why is no `stringr` package loaded in your sessionInfo

Comment: works fine with `string-1.3.0`.

Comment: drmariod, thanks, I executed/pasted out of sequence -- have corrected the post.

Comment: this is `stringi` and not `stringr`...

Comment: @drmariod, I don't understand your `stringi` comment; my editing of the post may help clarify.  As you can see post-edit, I am on `stringr` 1.3.0, and my `stringi` appears to be the latest on CRAN as well.

Comment: but `stringr` isn't loaded in your session info! You loaded `stringi`. Could you restart your R session and execute the 4 lines you posted and update again the `sessionInfo()`

Comment: OK.  Output is identical, including the `sessionInfo()`.  As a check, I edited one of the `str_glue_data()` commands to say `stringr::str_glue_data()` explicitly, but it doesn't make a difference.  I thought that `stringr` being attached was the key thing.  (We should probably take this discussion out of public comments if it needs to continue; thanks for continuing to help.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168891/discussion-between-drmariod-and-david-kaufman).